# Why :$\int\frac{dx}{a^2+x^2}= \frac 1a \tan^{-1}(\frac x a )$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I have tried many times to get the way to proof the below identity using trigonometric substitution but i can't  , Then Is there any simple way to know why $(1)$ is defined by this form ?

$$\int\frac{dx}{a^2+x^2}= \frac 1a \tan^{-1}(\frac x a )\tag{1}$$ ?

**Note:** For the specific question why exactly : $\int\frac{dx}{1+x^2}= \tan^{-1} x$ ?

Comment: Substitute $x=au$, and use that $(\tan^{-1}(x))'=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: $$\frac{dx}{a^2 + x^2} = \frac 1 {a^2} \frac{dx}{1 + (x/a)^2} = \frac 1 a \frac{d(x/a)}{1 + (x/a)^2}.$$

Comment: I meant the proof for the standard integral : why for example : integral (1/x²+1)= arctan (x ) ?

Comment: It might help: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation

Comment: You can do so by proving the derivative of $\arctan{x}$ is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ which you can use implicit differentiation for

Comment: @zeraouliarafik That's a standard fact contained in most calculus textbooks, or in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_of_trigonometric_functions#Differentiating_the_inverse_tangent_function).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would substitute $x=a\tan \theta$ and use the identity $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$. Then

\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{a^2+x^2}&=\int\frac{a\sec^2\theta}{a^2+a^2\tan^2\theta}\,d\theta \\
&=\int\frac{a\sec^2\theta}{a^2(1+\tan^2\theta)}\,d\theta \\
&=\frac{1}{a}\int\frac{\sec^2\theta}{\sec^2\theta}\,d\theta \\
&=\frac{1}{a}\int d\theta \\
&=\frac{1}{a}\theta+C \\
&=\frac{1}{a}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C
\end{align}
Since, from our substitution, $$\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

This integral $$\int\frac{dx}{a^2+x^2}= \frac 1a \tan^{-1}(\frac x a )\tag{1}$$

simply means that  derivative of   $$\frac 1a \tan^{-1}(\frac x a )\tag{1}$$ is $$ \frac{1}{a^2+x^2}$$

You may differentiate to verify the result.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{1}{a^2+x^2}dx$$

Apply Integral Substitution: $x=au$
$$=\int \frac{1}{a(u^2+1)}\,du$$
$$=\frac1a\int \frac{1}{u^2+1}\,du$$
Now use the formula:$\int \frac{1}{u^2+1}\,du=\arctan(u)$

$$=\frac1a \arctan(u)$$

Substitute back $u=\frac xa$

$$\frac1a \arctan(\frac xa)$$
$$\int \frac{1}{a^2+x^2}\,dx=\frac1a \arctan(\frac xa)+C$$